# AngularJS Only Show View If Server Data Present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my regular Javascript I append data to HTML **ONLY** if there's data from the server, otherwise I just show a simple `div` saying there's nothing. How can I implement this in AngularJS?

Example:

```
if (AJAXresult) 
    $element.append(JSONdata); //JSONdata will contain a list of customer data
else
    $element.append('<div>No results</div>');
```

How can I achieve this in Angular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way would be to control for the no data state in your returned view.

```
<div>
   <div ng-if="!hasCustomers">
     No Customers Available
   </div>
   <div ng-if="hasCustomers">
     <!-- show some stuff -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you can easily initialize this when you load your data:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, myDataService){
    $scope.hasCustomers = false;

    myDataService.getCustomers()
    .then(function(value){
        $scope.customers = value.data;

        $scope.hasCustomers = customers && customers.length;        
    });
});
```

If you want to make sure the data is loaded before your view is ever instantiated, then you can also use the `resolve` property on your `$route`

```
$routeProvider.when('/someRoute/',{
   templateUrl: '/sometemplate.html',
   controller: 'MyController',
   controllerAs: 'ctrl', // <-- Highly recommend you do this
   resolve: {
      customerData: function(myDataService){
          return myDataService.getCustomers();
      }
   }
});
```

`resolve` is basically a hash of functions that return a promise, and can be dependency injected just like everything else. The controller and view will not be loaded until all the `resolve` promises have been fulfilled.

It will be available in your controller by the same property name you gave it:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyController', function($scope, customerData){
   $scope.customers = customerData;
   $scope.hasCustomers = customerData && customerData.length;
});
```

Comment: Beautifully done. Another question, is there a way in AngularJS to have a view in a separate HTML file and just load IF the condition is met, for example?

Comment: @user3704920 I don't know your exact scenario, so I can only speculate, but loading a view based on a condition sounds like you really want to use `ng-include` instead. You could have it wrapped inside an `ng-if` and then as soon as the condition is true, it will automatically load the view. `ng-if` prevents all further processing on that node.

Comment: Perfect! see I am a beginner and I had no idea about the include directive, much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! In my case ng-if="condition" didn't work instead ng-show="condition" did it.